# java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.x.x.x}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

Caused by

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID 2131362837
> is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is null
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.getBackStackEntry(NavController.java:1358)
> at com.motorgy.consumerapp.util.extention.FragmentsKt.getStateSharedGraphViewModel$default(FragmentsKt.java:51)
> at com.motorgy.consumerapp.presentation.ui.featuredlist.FeaturedListFragment$special$$inlined$sharedGraphViewModel$default$1.invoke(FeaturedListFragment.java:129)
> at com.motorgy.consumerapp.util.extention.FragmentsKt$sharedGraphViewModel$1.invoke(FragmentsKt.java:41)
> at com.motorgy.consumerapp.presentation.ui.featuredlist.FeaturedListFragment$special$$inlined$sharedGraphViewModel$default$1.invoke(FeaturedListFragment.java:41)

I was only able to get the crash info from the crashlytics. Till now I am not able to produce the crash myself.

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.sharedGraphViewModel(
    @IdRes navGraphId: Int,
    qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
    bundle: Bundle? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
): Lazy<T> {
    return lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        getStateSharedGraphViewModel(
            navGraphId,
            T::class,
            qualifier,
            bundle,
            parameters }}




 inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getStateSharedGraphViewModel(
    @IdRes navGraphId: Int,
    clazz: KClass<T>,
    qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
    bundle: Bundle? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
): T {
    val owner = findNavController().getBackStackEntry(navGraphId)
    val bundleOrDefault: Bundle = bundle ?: Bundle()
    return getKoin().getStateViewModel(owner, clazz, qualifier, bundleOrDefault, parameters)
}
```

I am sharing same graph with multiple activities :
here is how I used the graph

```
    navControl =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                ?.let {
                    NavHostFragment.findNavController(it)
                }
        navControl?.let {
            val navInflater: NavInflater = it.navInflater
            val graph: NavGraph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
graph.startDestination = R.id.homeFragment
it.graph = graph
        }
```

Comment: log say:  The current destination is null at androidx.navigation.NavController.getBackStackEntry.... maybe you need to check if there is a link between fragments/activities

Comment: @DoctorWho There is. It works 99% of the time.